# Connection between MCUs with PHY peripherals

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, phy, mac

I plan to use a MAC TO MAC communication. RMII is decided to be used.

One processor is [SAMA5D27](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAMA5D2-Series-Datasheet-ds60001476.pdf) and the other is [S32K148](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf).

The signal connections seems to be OK.
But would this configuration work? Also should I need to connect the management (MDC & MDIO) interface B/w MCU & MPU?

Comment: Do both devices allow MAC-to-MAC connections? Are MDC and MDIO outputs or inputs? That defines if it will work and if you even can connect the management interfaces together.

Comment: @Justme NXP S32K148 mentioned MAC to MAC connection(but that too about Ethernet Switch nothing about MCU or MPU), but in SAMA5D27 i didn't see anything about MAC to MAC connection(that's where started getting doubts).

Comment: @Justme, Regarding MDC and MDIO in both device MDC is Output and MDIO is Input/output, with this configuration we can't connect these signals. The reason for asking about management interface is to know about any protocol dependencies.(i.e generally in switch or phy Management interface will initially configure the registers and after that MII or RMII or RGMII will start), but in this case it looks like Management interface can't be used.